# Cannot connect to X server as root

Tags: shell, x11, root

Whenever I try to run any X application as root, this happens:

```
root@penguin:~# scribus
No protocol specified
scribus: cannot connect to X server :0
```

If I run `echo $XAUTHORITY` on either root or the primary user it is empty, just returns an empty line.

```
Running ./Xauthority in either home directory:
-bash: ./Xauthority: No such file or directory
```

It also does not help to run `xhost +localhost`

Comment: Do you need to run scribus as root?

Comment: Scribus was just an example; no display works. Although it does seem that scribbus needs to be run as root to access much of my files